# How can I let action execute only now being checked ?

Tags: python, pyqt

I create the `popmenu` in `pushButton_6`.
There are three actions in popmenu , and each action can only radio .
The action is used to adjust how to play the song .
I have a problem that the action is triggered will be remembered .

For example , 
The song's list : ABCDEFG , and now is playing A .
when I click the ordered action before random action .
The song will first with ordered(song B) , then with random (Suppose now randomly to E).
So it plays the song E .
But I want the song just play with random , because it has now been converted into a state of random.

Another example,
when I click the ordered action ,then random action and finally by ordered action.
The song will first with ordered(song B) , then with random (Suppose now randomly to E) , and finally with ordered.(song F)
But I want the song just play with ordered , because it has now been converted into a state of ordered.
So the song should plays B not F .

How can I let action execute only now being checked ?
By the way , can popmenu be show up ?

Here is code of popmenu.

```
        popmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.ui.pushButton_6)
        group = QtGui.QActionGroup(self.ui.pushButton_6)
        group.setExclusive(True)

        for i in range(1, 4):
            if i==1:
                action = group.addAction('ordered')
                action.setCheckable(True)
                #action.setChecked(True) 

            if i==2:
                action = group.addAction('replay')
                action.setCheckable(True)

            if i==3:
                action = group.addAction('random')
                action.setCheckable(True)


            popmenu.addAction(action)
        self.ui.pushButton_6.setMenu(popmenu)
        group.triggered.connect(self.sortedEvent)
```

Here is code of sortedEvent.

```
def sortedEvent(self,action):       
        if action.text()=="ordered":
            print(action.text())                                    
            self.connect(self.mediaObject,QtCore.SIGNAL('finished()'),self.ordered)

        if action.text()=="replay":
            print(action.text())               
            self.connect(self.mediaObject,QtCore.SIGNAL('aboutToFinish()'),self.replay)

        if action.text()=="random":
            print(action.text())                
            self.connect(self.mediaObject,QtCore.SIGNAL('finished()'),self.random)
```

Comment: As a general rule, if the conditions are exclusive - `group.setExclusive(true)`, then you should use `else if` conditional statements. I'm still looking for a proper solution though.

Comment: To show the pop-up menu on mouse click, `QMenu.exec(QCursor.pos())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect` are additive, they do not replace each other. With your code, if I click on "ordered" then "random", the `finished` signal will be connected to two slots: `self.ordered` and `self.random`. I don't think it's the behaviour you're expected.

Instead, you could have a `string` value, let's call it `whatToDoNext`. A click on the menu set the string to the action's text:

```
def sortedEvent(self,action):       
    self.whatToDoNext=action.text()
```

In your case, `whatToDoNext` can be "ordered", "random" or "replay".
The `finished` signal of `mediaObject` is always connected to the same function:

```
self.mediaObject.finished.connect(self.on_finish)

def on_finish(self):
    if self.whatToDoNext=="ordered":
        #read the next song
    elif self.whatToDoNext=="random":
        #read a random song
    else:
        #replay
```

Comment: I have done according to what you say  .But when I click "ordered" ,order of songs is wrong .It plays the next song at first time , and next plays the next third song ,then plays the next  ninth song .

Comment: I think it has to do with what you wrote in `#read the next song`

Comment: But I found the same situation also occurred "random" . I tried  using "print(path)" , and the program will be executed once ,then three times ,finally executed night times .

Comment: I can't make sense of what you say. Perhaps you should post another question. Be sure to put all the relevant code, but no more, and describe the current behaviour and the expected behaviour.

Comment: OK ! Thanks for your help :)))